# Java: Ideal file format to store a hashmap in?

Tags: java, file, hashmap

I need to save an arraylist of hashmaps to an external file. I can use any format expect for a text file, because the program is set to ignore text files (specially, anything with a `.txt` extension). The hashmaps are pretty straightforward, just words with counts of those words. What is the ideal file format to store this in?

Comment: Remember that Java doesn't care about extensions unless you make it care about extensions (i.e. by filtering on extensions, for example). Windows cares, but Java doesn't care if you name it `java.txt` or `java.reallyrandomextension`, if it contains text data, Java can read it as a text file regardless of its extension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`java.util.Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html).

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.putAll(yourMap); // You could also just use Properties in first place.

try (OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/foo.properties")) {
    properties.store(output, null);
}
```

You can read it later by

```
Properties properties = new Properties();

try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream("/foo.properties")) {
    properties.load(input);
}

// ... (Properties implements Map, you could just treat it like a Map)
```

#### See also:

- [Java Tutorials - Essential Classes - Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html)

Comment: +1, though of course, you should make sure to close those streams ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use serialization:

```
    ObjectOutputStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        File f = new File(filename);
        stream = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(f));
        stream.writeObject(your_arraylist);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```

And read it in using:

```
    ObjectInputStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        your_arrayList = (your_arrayList type here)stream.readObject();
    }
    catch (Throwable t)
    {
        // Handle error
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            try
            {
                stream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    }
```